# Views complex sort

Tags: 7, views

I have a Drupal view which displays 10 items. I have 3 items which need to remain at the top of the list, which i have done by making them sticky. These need to be in a particular order. The the rest of the list then needs to be in alphabetical order. How can I do this?

Here are my current view settings:

```
Title
Title: None
Format
Format: Unformatted list | Settings
Show: Fields | Settings
open

    Add

Fields
Content: thumb
Content: Title
Content: Body
Content: Link
open

    Add

Filter criteria

Content: Published (Yes)
Content: Type (= Mineral)
Content: Title (!= others)
open

    Add

Sort criteria
Content: Sticky (desc)
Content: Title (asc)
Block settings
Block name: minerals
Access: Permission | View published content

    Add

Header

    Add

Footer
Pager
Use pager: Display a specified number of items |  items
More link: No
Advanced

    Add

Contextual filters

    Add

Relationships

    Add

No results behavior
Exposed form
Exposed form style: Basic | Settings
Other
Machine Name: block
Comment: No comment
Use AJAX: No
Hide attachments in summary: No
Hide contextual links: No
Use aggregation: No
Query settings: Settings
Field Language: Current user's language
Caching: None
Link display: None
CSS class: None
Theme: Information
Block caching: Do not cache
```

Comment: Can you also mention how your result coming up now?

Comment: the 3 sticky nodes are at the top of the list, in alpha order and then the remainder of the list is alpha. I need the 3 sticky nodes to be in a different order. Can i apply  a sort to only them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you ask about how to show the sticky ones in a particular order, you can add anonther custom field (e.g. "position") to the content-type. Define a number for the position and add another filter criteria for this custom field.

The sort criteria for the position should be set before the other sort filters.